# How to append css to zend project?

Tags: css, image, zend-framework

I can not append image or css file in my zend project.I put my css file into

```
project/public/css/style.css .
```

My page can not include this css file. When I copy css file url redirect to my homepage.  however if i type anything in end of my url address redirect to my home page.

For example when I go to  `/project.com/asdsadasda` I do not get any errors and it renders the homepage but with wrong address.

Comment: What URL are you going to to be redirected to the homepage? Also please edit your question to include the contents of `public/.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

In your bootstrap.php file add this:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers()
   {
      $this->bootstrap('layout');
      $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
      $view = $layout->getView();
      $view->headLink()->setStylesheet('/css/style.css');  // your CSS file
   }
```

And in your layout.phtml add this lines in top:

```
<head>
<?php echo $this->headMeta() ?>
<?php echo $this->headTitle() ?>
<?php echo $this->headLink()?> </head>
```

EDIT.

If you don't know how to turn on layout support in Zend Framework read this tutorial:
http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/simple-zend_layout-example/

Comment: my main problem is no address doesn't work if i type any thing in my url doesn't get any error

Comment: I created error contoller.
And zend FW think css folder is controller.how can i fix this problem:

Comment: Bootstrap should be used only for global css-es, not any files that are specific for a controller.

Answer (score 0):

To effectively use your css file, you need to create a `Layout`. let says `Layout.phtml` is your layout then the `head` can reference you css file this way :

```
<html>

<head>
<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/style.css'); ?>
....
</head>

....
```

good chance

Comment: I created layout:  <?php echo $this->docType(); ?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <? echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/style.css') ?> 
 </head>
 <body>